# How to do integration tests for Firebase HTTP functions with Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, integration-testing

Trying to write integrations tests for HTTPS function (implemented as an express app) that use Firestore as DB

Since its an integration test, I don't want to mock the Firestore DB in this case, however, since they perform network calls, they take time to execute

Is there a Firestore local emulator to use in this scenario? There is an option to config Firestore in offline mode, maybe that's the way? Didn't find any documentation in Firebase on this use case

## AskFirebase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to setup a Firestore emulator locally (assuming you already have `firebase-cli` installed):

`$ firebase setup:emulators:firestore`

Then run the emulator:

`$ firebase serve --only firestore`

With the emulator running, you can run your test suites.

In order to write tests you can use the `@firebase/testing` package. For more information, check the official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator).

There is also an official quickstart repository on GitHub, which shows how to test Firestore locally, both using JavaScript and Typescript. You can find it [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/tree/master/firestore-emulator).

Comment: I don't actually see any examples of testing functions in that repo, HTTP or otherwise. I'm a bit confused, as all the examples of the `@firebase/testing` package talk about testing the database, not functions.